# How and when do I need to use notifyOnChanges on QueryList in Agular?

Tags: angular

I was looking through the `QueryList` API and was confused by the `notifyOnChanges` method.
So, there is a `changes` Observable that I can subscribe to, and it would notify me when a QueryList changes.

This is a small example I created to better understand `changes`  Observable, and it makes sense to me:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template: `
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
    <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    <button (click)="addToArray()">Add +</button>
    <br>
    <app-child *ngFor="let elem of numberOfComponents"> <p #p>Here is some text</p> </app-child>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  numberOfComponents = [1, 1];

  @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) queryList: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

  addToArray() {
    this.numberOfComponents.push(1);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.queryList.changes.subscribe((change) =>
      console.log(change, 'this is a change')
    );
  }

}
```

Now, when it comes to notifyOnChanges, Angular documentation is saying:

> Triggers a change event by emitting on the changes EventEmitter.

This doesn't tell me how and when to use it. I'd appreciate if you could provide an example that answers both questions.

Comment: You're doing the correct approach at your example, because in the main documentation file they say **Returns `Observable` of `QueryList` notifying the subscriber of changes.** so when you are subscribing to the "changes" observable is right, also ngAfterViewInit is right place tp subscribe because we need to had been rendered the list of components.  [Repository Angular QueryList](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/17.0.4/packages/core/src/linker/query_list.ts#L59)

Answer (score 0):

When change, you can makes any action:

Typical use can be when you want to focus to the last created. Imagine you have in your app-child an input with `ViewChild('myInput') myInput:ElementRef`

```
this.queryList.changes.subscribe((change) =>
  this.queryList.last.myInput.nativeElement.focus()
);
```

Or you want to scroll to the last element. If you have in app-child in constructor inject the ElementRef: `constructor(public el:ElementRef){}`

```
this.queryList.changes.subscribe((change) =>
  this.queryList.last.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", });
);
```

Or you want change a property "selected" of all of them

```
this.queryList.changes.subscribe((change) =>
  this.queryList.forEach(x=>x.selected=x==this.queryList.last)
);
```

Or...

Comment: Thank you, however, my question was about `notifyOnChanges` method on the QueryList.  I understand how to work with the `changes` observable, and as stated  in the question, I have no idea how to use notifyOnChanges.